# Google App Engine Java with IntelliJ Community Edition

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

Is it possible to use App Engine Java with IntelliJ Community Edition? I know there is an official plugin for Ultimate Edition.

I would like to:

- have a run/debug configuration
- deploy to app engine

Answer (score 6):

Community Edition doesn't have this feature, [check the matrix](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), I'm also not aware of any third-party plug-ins that would add this functionality to the Community Edition.

Comment: Sadly this is true most of the time with the IDEA family. If there's official support for something there's no free alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the Ultimate Edition to develop for App Engine, just download the EAP:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.1+EAP

I've used Community EAP for a year, only to realize that the Ultimate pre-release version is free.

I've used EAP for 1.5 years now and it's not less stable than the releases, which is sad, but true.
If you report bugs that are real issues, you can get a fix turnaround of 1-2 weeks with EAP.
So far no issue have been serious enough to prevent me from using the IDE, just minor annoyances.
Even if it happens you can just downgrade to a previous EAP build after filing a bug in YouTrack.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, thanks ! Unfortunately, it seems to only be a 30 day "evaluation" thing, meaning I can't download it once and keep using it forever ? (I'm looking for something which is free)

Comment: As I said it updates every 1-2 weeks which renews the 30 days. I've been using it for 2 months now.

Comment: Oh, ok, will try it, and you'll probably get the bounty :-)

Comment: It's also worth just start using it, and in the meantime look for alternatives if you don't like being on the bleeding edge. Don't let this impede your development.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if that would be acceptable, but Android Studio - which is free and based on IntelliJ Community edition - offers integration with Google App Engine.

Sample link: https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/app_engine/add_module

Comment: This looks great ! I've been using Android Studio for some time now, but never thought of using it for App Engine too. Will definitely try it out.